# Website double sign in with Facebook and/or Email

Tags: php, facebook, email, authentication, passwords

I am planning the development of a website that rely heavily on facebook integration, for this reason I will primarily push the user to use the "facebook login" option. For some reason, I don't want to leave out users that doesn't like to login with Facebook, so I will implement a classic user registration with email and password.

Now my questions are:

- what is the correct way to manage both logins? Should I store fb user data on a record, saving at first login (as a registration) their fb_userid as a reference to use their data on my app? Can I get and store (with user agreement of course) their facebook email on the first visit?
- What happens if users that have registered with email only, one day want to login with facebook? Will this create a new user record or should I merge the two logins in a unique user record?
- Do I need to set cookies and session for fb users or not?

I see a lot of websites now that are using this double login but I never figured out how they manage it. In the first time I was thinking to use facebook login only, but a lot of people suggested that is a bad idea. What do you think?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have the same thing. what i do:

my users table has: id, facebook_uid, email, password

1. if someone fconnects - i create a new user for him, unique AI id, set the facebook user id, the email, and generate a random password. i'm sending him the password by mail.
2. if someone registers - facebook uid is 0
3. someone tries to registered and email already exists with a facebook id - he has the password in the mail or can use forgot password etc.
4. someone tries to fconnect and email already exists - i use the already existing account:

my approach is, i can verify the email by sending him a confirmation link. fconnect is confirmation for me. in this case, i want to give him the account (since he owns the email). i can ask him to enter the password and regenerate one and send him.

of course, you can handle each of these cases differently - basic approach - verified email = you own an account. fconnect = verified email

**EDIT: to note**
once a user has fconnected - i set the login parameters in the session/cookie. i don't want to make a request to the facebook servers on every page view

Comment: this seems the way to manage it. Thanks for being clear and concise ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you store just the token or more data? Don't mind the stupid question, this is my first php project that is not a form ;)

Comment: you can store the token, really depends on what you do. in one of my projects i don't save it. in another project i do since i'm fetching user data (such as friends list) in the background (on the server using system daemons) so it won't depend on the user's browsing etc.